# Interview question medium, a little help please

Tags: python

A train has a maximum capacity of n passengers overall, which means each carriage's capacity will share an equal proportion of the maximum capacity.

Create a function which returns the index of the first carriage which holds 50% or less of its maximum capacity. If no such carriage exists, return -1.

```
find_a_seat(200, [35, 23, 18, 10, 40]) ➞ 2

# There are 5 carriages which each have a maximum capacity of 40 (200 / 5 = 40).
# Index 0's carriage is too full (35 is 87.5% of the maximum).
# Index 1's carriage is too full (23 is 57.5% of the maximum).
# Index 2's carriage is good enough (18 is 45% of the maximum).
# Return 2.

def find_a_seat(n, lst):
    a = n // len(lst)
    return [[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j / a <= 0.5]+[-1]][0][0]



print(find_a_seat(200, [35, 23, 18, 10, 40]))
```

Can you please explain why are we looping i for i, and not using it futher, and the end of solution --> [-1]][0][0] -- what does it exactly do

Comment: The code you provide is fairly compact. You need to research `list comprehensions` with an `if` clause (which is a filter).

Comment: it's `[solution+[-1]]` first. it just adds -1 to the list of the solution. the solution is in the form `[[2,-1]]` so solution [0][0] just selects the real solution or -1 if there's no solution.

Comment: `next((i for i, v in enumerate([35, 23, 18, 10, 40]) if v <= 200 / 5 * 0.5), -1)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Multiplies are generally easier to understand than divides.  When comparing ratios, it is generally best to multiply both sides by the denominators of the opposite side, eliminating the need for any division.  A right shift is just another way to do integer division, which is unnecessary (and then you have to think about truncation).  The best way to compare `a/b <= c/d` is to instead compare `a*d <= b*c`.  This is pretty standard.

Comment: @TomKarzes, you can't avoid division and/or floating point math if percent comes from input, so

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, sometimes it can't be avoided.  But often it can, such as this case.  A very common example that you see on SO all the time is change calculators. People will try to do it in floating point, and as a result they will encounter roundoff errors and their answer will be wrong, so they post here for help.  The answer is to keep everything in terms of pennies, eliminating the need for floating point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j / a <= 0.5]` returns the list of carriages with capacity ≤ 50%, **if any**. This means that if there are none, this will be an empty list.

The `[i for i in X if condition]` acts as a filter: for each element in X, keep them if they match the condition. Here `enumerate(lst)` give the index (i) and the value (j) for each step of the loop.

Then `+[-1]` adds `-1` at the end of the list. If will thus be the first item if the previous list is empty.

Finally `[0][0]` slices the first item, either the first carriage number with capacity ≤ 50%, or -1

##### demonstration with provided example:

```
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j / a <= 0.5]
[2, 3]
>>> [[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j / a <= 0.5]+[-1]]
[[2, 3, -1]]
>>> [[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j / a <= 0.5]+[-1]][0]
[2, 3, -1]
>>> [[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j / a <= 0.5]+[-1]][0][0]
2
```

##### possible alternative

This solution stops at the first match (if any), else returns -1

```
from itertools import dropwhile
a = n // len(lst)
n = 200
lst = [35, 23, 18, 10, 40]
next(dropwhile(lambda i: lst[i]/a>0.5, range(len(lst))), -1)
```